# SSIS derived column very slow (date manipulation)

Tags: sql, datetime, ssis, derived

**SETUP**: I have a very large **SSIS** package that sorts through a lot of different **flat files** and throws them into tables that fit the file definitions to a T... except the date.  The dates come over in the format: `"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.ffffff."`  Of course, for **dbtimestamp**, this needs to be converted to `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ffffff"`.  On any given file I have at least 2 dates; created and updated.  On some I have more.

**PROBLEM**: of the 26 files I parse, one is particularly larger than the other.  In some cases it can be 40+ MB.  It seemed to be running fine before, but running through a derived column component that derives 3 dates is now EXTREMELY slow.  It takes around **30 minutes to parse ~90,600 rows.**

I'm watching the data flow as it is executing and the bottleneck looks very much like the derived column.  I report all error rows if they happen to exist and there are none, so I know it's not choking on the rows... I just can't figure out what is taking so long.  The **CPU** shoots up to 100% while executing (no big surprise) but the **memory** stays low at 12%.

**Here's the exact transformation** that happens on each of 3 dates for each line:

```
(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)(SUBSTRING(COLUMN,7,4) + "-" + SUBSTRING(COLUMN,1,2) 
 + "-" + SUBSTRING(COLUMN,4,2) + SUBSTRING(COLUMN,11,14))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It looks fine to me. First you need to prove it's this line. Remove it and see if the performance hit still occurs. If not you need to hunt harder. If it does go, my first inclination is try for script transformer and see if it gives more clues such as some line being  accidently 40 megs long. This thing I find with SSIS is that it's temperamental and that some things that look like they should be trivial can actually be quite hard to debug.

Comment: Preet, that was a very good idea.  It really seemed like the derived column was the bottleneck, but it was further down the line.  Turns out when I copied the database and mirrored it to a test DB (because there were MAJOR changes to the SSIS package), none of the constraints came over.  I re-established them all and now the whole thing is under 2.5 minutes :).

Comment: Good work. Please Put the details in an answer for next poor person that has to work with that horrible (:-) technology!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied the DB because of the extensive changes and **the indexes were not brought over properly.**  This slowed the biggest table down.  Removing the derived step helped me figure out that it was further down the line, despite the fact that monitoring the SSIS execution of the data flow made it *seem* as thought it was the derived step.

I realize this is probably not going to happen often, but I'll leave the thread here in case anyone else has the problem and mistakenly identifies it like I did!